# Least painful way of not using int4 as primary key in Django user models?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I'm new to Django, and upon running the first migration, it seems the primary key ID of the `auth_users` table is an int4. Looking through the docs, it seems if I use any kind of custom User model, for example to bigint or uuid, I am opening a can of worms and losing Django Admin functionality and possibly all sorts of auth scaffolding functionality?

Is there a standard way of not using int4 that I'm failing to see, let's say using UUID, short of going full custom on the auth backend?

Tried custom model extending `django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser`. Django Admin stops working, which seems expected according to documentation. However, auth scaffolding, such as `python manage.py createsuperuser` also starts throwing errors, such as `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "id" of relation "users_user" violates not-null constraint`. This is when `id` is a Postgres UUID.

Here's the User model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
```

Comment: The Django admin shouldn't stop working if you set your `AUTH_USER_MODEL`  accordingly (as discussed [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)). What's the exact trouble you're having?

Comment: @AKX think I have my terminology mixed up. In fact the /admin page shows the login, but I can't use the createsuperuser command, as it throws that null value error in the OP.

Comment: Oh heck I didn't define a default UUID value, let me try that real quick..

Comment: Right - your original post didn't show your custom ID field. You'd need to have a `default=...` function generating an UUID for you for that field, e.g. `default=uuid.uuidv4`.

Comment: Ok we're good for now it seems. Thanks @AKX, somehow reading your comment made me realize I never defined a default UUID value haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make my (implied) comment an answer:

if you don't specify an `AutoField()` (i.e. "let the database decide") as your primary key, you'll need to specify *some* implicit primary key.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

is an obvious way to generate a random UUIDv4 for a new model, or if you like to have more control, e.g. via ULIDs, you could use [ulid2](https://github.com/valohai/ulid2):

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=ulid2.generate_ulid_as_uuid)
```

Comment: Oh, ulid2 looks quite useful. Will be using that, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! It's artisanal code by yours truly. 